# Add a div to the top of react bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using this react-bootstrap table:
[image]
which it's HTML code is:

```
 <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
```

I was trying to add the code here.

```
                   <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>App</th>
                    <th>Domain Name</th>
                    <th>Pub Account ID</th>
                    <th>Relationship</th>
                    <th>Certification ID</th>
                    <th>Last update</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" id={'checkboxThick'+network.id} onClick={()=>this.checkCheckbox(network.id)}/></th>
                    <td>{network.product}</td>
                    <td>{network.domain_Name}</td>
                    <td>{network.publisher_Id}</td>
                    <td>{network.relationship}</td>
                    <td>{network.certification_Id}</td>
                    <td>{network.lastUpdate}</td>
                    <td className="actionCoulmn">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </Table>
```

And I need to add this div as a part of the table:

[image]

I was trying to add some divs and styles to the `<tr>` and `<th>` with no success.
Does someone have any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could settle with this:

```
  <div id="parent">
     <div /> // your div here
     <table /> // your existing table component
   </div>
```

and use styling to merge them